# Determine version of a specific package

Tags: julia

How can I get the version number for a specific package?

The obvious way is to get the dictionary with all installed packages, and then filter for the one of interest:

```
pkgs = Pkg.installed();
pkgs["Datetime"]
```

Getting the list of all installed packages is very slow though, especially if there are many packages.

Comment: ``pkgs["Datetime"]`` does nothing for me: Julia version ``0.5.2``.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**EDIT: For Julia version 1.1+**

Use the [Pkg REPL](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Pkg/) notation:

```
] status                        # Show every installed package version
] status pkgName                # Show the specific version of the package
] status pkgName1 pkgName2      # Show the named packages. You can continue the list.
```

The `]` enters the Pkg REPL, so you basically write `status ...`

So in your case, write after entering the Pkg REPL:

```
status DataFrame
```

Or use the object-oriented approach (NB: Here you don't enter the Pkg REPL, i.e. DON'T use `]`:

```
Pkg.status("DataFrame")
```

**EDIT:  For Julia version 1.0**

`Pkg.installed` seems to have "regressed" with the new package system. There are no arguments for `Pkg.installed`.  So, the OP's original method seems to be about the best you can do at the moment.

```
pkgs = Pkg.installed();
pkgs["Datetime"]
```

**EDIT:  For Julia version upto 0.6.4**

You can pass a string to `Pkg.installed`.  For example:

```
pkgs = Pkg.installed("JuMP")
```

I often check available calling arguments with `methods`.  For example:

```
julia> methods(Pkg.installed)
# 2 methods for generic function "installed":
installed() at pkg/pkg.jl:122
installed(pkg::AbstractString) at pkg/pkg.jl:129
```

or

```
julia> Pkg.installed |> methods
# 2 methods for generic function "installed":
installed() at pkg/pkg.jl:122
installed(pkg::AbstractString) at pkg/pkg.jl:129
```

Comment: In the REPL you can use a faster way, by typing TAB after the left parenthesis:

``julia> Pkg.installed(\tab``

Comment: @ivarne  Cool!  Didn't know that.  Thanks!  Any REPL sorcery for `methodswith`?

Comment: Not that I know about.

Comment: I get ``installed(pkg::AbstractString)`` as the second method.

Comment: I am getting `ERROR: MethodError: no method matching installed(::String)`. Could be the answer updated to 1.0.0? Hopefully now api will not be changing that often.

Comment: @jangorecki The OP was using `Pkg.installed`.  In version 1.0.0, I think you may need `using Pkg` first.

Comment: @jangorecki ... and I think `Pkg.installed` in version 1.0.0 and up may have a different meaning.  Perhaps the new meaning is "packages directly installed by the user, but not dependencies" rather than "all installed packages".  IDK for sure, I'm still on v0.6.4.

Comment: @JamesonQuinn indeed, no trace of `Pkg.installed` in the [Pkg API reference](https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/stable/api/)

Comment: all of this prints out the output, how would go go about storing the ouput into a variable

Comment: `Warning: Pkg.installed() is deprecated` For Julia Version 1.5.2 (at least). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25635704/10156184

Comment: @DisabledWhale I'm not currently a `Julia` user.  I've reassigned this answer to Community wiki.  Please feel free to update the answer for the latest `Julia` info.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry - I did not think of editing! All the best and thanks for pointing out :)

Comment: Note that you can `using`/`import` packages that are installed not in the current `activate`d environment, but further up in `LOAD_PATH`. Is there a way to get the version of all of these packages without needing to activate the environments separately?

Answer (score 13):

I would try `Pkg.status("PackageName")`

This will print out a little blurb giving the package name.

Here is an example

```
julia> Pkg.status("QuantEcon")
 - QuantEcon                     0.0.1              master
```

Comment: `Pkg.status("QuantEcon")` gives me `ERROR: 'status' has no method matching status(::ASCIIString)` in julia 0.3.  Is the method part of a particular package?

Comment: Oh interesting. That is not a method of that package. I am on 0.4dev so maybe it is a new function.

Comment: @JamesonQuinn, indeed since Julia 1.x `Pkg` needs to be imported.

Comment: julia> Pkg.status("LinearAlgebra")
Status `C:\Users\joe\.julia\environments\v1.5\Project.toml`
  [37e2e46d] LinearAlgebra
But it doesn't tell me the version.

Answer (score 9):

In `Julia 1.1` you can use

```
(v1.1) pkg> status "name_of_the_package"
```

to find the version of any package in a given environment.

Answer (score 2):

In order to look of a version of an indirectly included package (e.g. top-level project includes Module A which depends on Module B, where you need to know info about Module B), you have to pull the info either from the Manifest.toml directly, or you have to bring in the `Context` object in from `Pkg`.

Below is done with Julia 1.3.1 ... there may be changes to `Pkg`'s internals since then.

```
using Pkg
using UUIDs

ctx = Pkg.Operations.Context()

# Get the version of CSV.jl
version = ctx.env.manifest[UUID("336ed68f-0bac-5ca0-87d4-7b16caf5d00b")].version
if version <= v"0.5.24"
    # handle some uniqueness about the specific version of CSV.jl here
end
```

UPDATE: Or without a UUID and just the package name (thanks @HHFox):

```
using Pkg

pkg_name = "Observables"
m = Pkg.Operations.Context().env.manifest

v = m[findfirst(v->v.name == pkg_name, m)].version
```

or to do the same with the `Manifest.toml`

```
using Pkg

# given the path to the Manifest.toml file...
manifest_dict = Pkg.TOML.parsefile(manifest_path)

# look for a named package like `CSV`
package_dict = manifest_dict[package_name][1]
@show package_dict
```

Comment: I like this solution. Here is a version that matches the name rather than the UUID
`using Pkg;

m = Pkg.Operations.Context().env.manifest;
v = m[findfirst(v->v.name=="Observables", m)].version`

Answer (score 0):

Well this didn't print well in the comment section...
Here is a version that matches the name rather than the UUID

```
using Pkg

m = Pkg.Operations.Context().env.manifest
v = m[findfirst(v -> v.name == "CSV", m)].version
```

Answer (score 0):

For packages which are dependencies of the specified packages in the project file one can use `status -m <packageName>` or shorter `st -m <packageName>` in package mode (`After` ]`).

For a full list, just use `st -m`.

This is an extension to https://stackoverflow.com/a/25641957.